# Installing phpunit - are the sebastian & symfony directories necessary?

Tags: phpunit

When installing phpunit 4.0 using composer (in PHPStorm) I get ....

```
/phpunit
/sebastian
/symfony
```

Does anyone know why I get the 2nd two and if there are necessary in any way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

these dependencies are necessary as you can see at the [composer file](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/composer.json) of PHPUnit. Before Composer was around and they shipped the software only via PEAR, you need to install all the dependencies by your own. At the end nothing changed.

In case you are concerned about installing all these dependencies over and over again for every PHP project you need PHPUnit, you can install it globally on you system.

Add `composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*'` to your composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those two directories are necessary for PHPUnit to work.

The dependencies in the `vendor` folder are managed by composer for you, you don't need to worry here. The reason you have them is because you installed PHPUnit.

When you remove PHPUnit and those dependencies aren't required by any other package, they will be removed again.